# Nginx with docker not working for web application

Tags: node.js, nginx, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to set up a container in docker for my react/flux webapp. I decided to go with an nginx server to handle the listening and routing.

This is the web.conf config file for nginx

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
            root /www/web_files;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
            index index.html;
            add_header expires off;
    }
}
```

Now, I deployed this on an amazon node in docker and can access it on the public IP of the VM.

http://54.238.176.11

Now, I want to setup my **/www/web_files** directory where nginx would search for $uri or index.html

This the docker file I have for my container for **web_files**. I deploy this on the same node as my nginx server.

```
FROM ubuntu 
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get -y install bash git openssh-client g++ gcc libc6-dev make curl 

RUN curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo bash - 
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs python 
RUN npm install -g npm@2.7.6

WORKDIR /app ADD . /app

RUN npm install 
RUN npm run build 
RUN rm -rf node_modules 
CMD rm -rf /www/web_files && cp -R ./build /www/web_files
```

So this should copy my ./build folder (generated by npm run build_ into /www/web_files.

Why is it that now, when i access the above IP address, I still get the nginx page. I would assume that it would open up the index.html or $uri page. Am I missing something here?

Comment: have you checked /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default file ? root /usr/share/nginx/html; or you should configure : server_name 54.238.176.11; below listen 80; in web.conf file

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand. What does root /usr/share/nginx/html mean? and why does server_name need to be the IP address? the nginx container is located at the same IP address. I assumed if I let the server_name blank, it would know!

Comment: default path of nginx is point to  /usr/share/nginx/html folder , so we have to give specify server_name parameter, it will map to /www/web_files folder as we point server_name 54.238.176.11; in web.conf file. Sorry my English.

Comment: Are you running two separate containers? The files need to be in the same container for Nginx to serve them.

Comment: As the comment above says, the files need to be either in the same container, or properly mounted to the container (check out docker volumes)

Comment: I am running on 2 separate containers. Reading about docker volumes, I understand now that I need to mount it so that it can be shared between containers! Thank you. Quick follow up questions: Is there any advantage to having my web_files and nginx on different containers? I had seen a previous setup like this and was trying to emulate